# Python Code to find the letter start with a in a sentence

Tags: python, string, function, for-loop

Here is the code to find the words start with a in the sentence: "This is an apple tree."

```
st = 'This is an apple tree'

for word in st.split():
    if word[0]=='a':
        print(word)
```

I want to make it to function, and takes in any sentence I want, how to to that?
Here is the code I came up, but is not doing what I want.

```
def find_words(text):
    for word in find_words.split():
        if word[0]=='a':
            print(word)
    return find_words

find_words('This is an apple tree')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below code. It will provide the list of words which has a word starts with 'a'.

This is simple list comprehension with if clause. Split without argument by default splits the sentence by space and startswith method helps to filter 'a'.

```py
sentence = 'This is an apple tree'
words = [word for word in sentence.split() if word.startswith('a')]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you are defining the for loop. It should be:

```
for word in text.split(' '):
     ...
```

Just because text is the parameter in your defined function

Comment: Thank you so much. It works, but why it also shows a warning: <function_main_.find_words(text)> ?

Comment: It is not a warning. Are you running find_words('this is an apple tree') or just find_words()?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the result try this:

```
st = 'This is an apple tree'

def find_words(text):
    for word in text.split():
        if word.startswith('a'):
            print(word)

find_words(st)
```